# How to query Neo4jRepository using a @StartNode relationship?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following nodes:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String firstName;

  private String lastName;

  private LocalDate birthday;

  @Email
  private String email;
}
```

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NodeEntity
public class Skill {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String name;

  private String description;
}
```

And this `RelationshipEntity`:

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@RelationshipEntity("RATED")
public class SkillRating {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Min(0)
  @Max(100)
  private Integer score;

  private LocalDate measurementDate;

  @StartNode
  private Person person;

  @EndNode
  private Skill skill;
}
```

I do not want to load relationships which I do not plan to use, i.e. I do not want to add:

```
@Relationship(type = "RATED")
private Set<SkillRating> skillRatings;
```

to my `Person` class definition to prevent these ratings from loading each time I load a `Person`. I would like to instead load these when necessary using `Repository` methods. This is what I tried using my knowledge of JPA repositories:

```
@Repository
public interface SkillRatingRepository extends Neo4jRepository<SkillRating, Long> {
  List<SkillRating> findAllByPerson(Person person);
}
```

But this method does not work as expected since it does not find any ratings for a person. What am I doing wrong?

-- EDIT --

```
MATCH (p)-[r:RATED]->(skill) WHERE id(p)={personId} RETURN r
```

I believe this is a query that solves my problem written in Neo4j Cypher query language. How can I "translate" it in a `Repository` method using my current class setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for asking.

As you noticed, we don't support derived finder methods based on objects. With `@RelationshipEntity` there's the additional restriction, that the derived finder methods only targets properties and not the end or start node.

Having said that, I have taken your project (the domain classes) and created a solution for you. So, domain classes `Person`, `Skill` and `SkillRating` can be used as is.

Please declare your `SkillRatingRepository` like this:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Query;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.Neo4jRepository;

public interface SkillRatingRepository extends Neo4jRepository<SkillRating, Long> {

    @Query("MATCH (p)-[r:RATED]->(skill) WHERE id(p) = :#{#person.id} RETURN p, r, skill")
    List<SkillRating> findAllByPerson(Person person);
}
```

`@Query` indicates a custom query. Inside that custom query, you can use *Spring Exression Language (SpEL)* as described here https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions.

Thus, you're dereference the passed person and access the id. Pretty much as in the query you already wrote. Take note that you have to return start and end node as well to make the mapping work.

If you run a standard Spring Boot project, than parameter names are retained during compilation and no other annotation is needed. If you don't retain them, please add `@Param("person")` to the parameter.

I noticed that you're using a `LocalDate` in your domain. Those are supported natively with Neo4j 3.4+ and the Java (aka Bolt) Driver.

In the current version of Spring Data Neo4j and Neo4j-OGM distributed with Spring Boot 2.1.8 those can be activated as shown in the following test (scroll down to the `Config` class annotated with `@TestConfiguration`):

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration;
import org.neo4j.ogm.driver.ParameterConversionMode;
import org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestConfiguration
public class SkillRatingRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private SkillRatingRepository skillRatingRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Test
    public void retrievalOfSkillsShouldWork() {
        Skill s = Skill.builder().name("Java")
            .description("The Number one programming language everyone loves and hates").build();

        new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager).execute(t -> {
            session.purgeDatabase();
            return null;
        });

        Person ms = Person.builder()
            .firstName("Michael")
            .lastName("Simons")
            .build();
        Person gm = Person.builder()
            .firstName("Gerrit")
            .lastName("M")
            .build();
        SkillRating r1 = SkillRating
            .builder().person(ms)
            .skill(s).measurementDate(LocalDate.now()).score(23).build();
        SkillRating r2 = SkillRating
            .builder().person(gm)
            .skill(s).measurementDate(LocalDate.now()).score(42).build();

        skillRatingRepository.saveAll(Arrays.asList(r1, r2));

        List<SkillRating> skillRatings =
            skillRatingRepository.findAllByPerson(gm);
        assertThat(skillRatings).hasSize(1);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    static class Config {

        @Bean
        public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
            Configuration.Builder builder = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration.Builder();
            builder.uri("bolt://localhost:7687");
            builder.credentials("neo4j", "secret");
            builder.withCustomProperty(ParameterConversionMode.CONFIG_PARAMETER_CONVERSION_MODE,
                ParameterConversionMode.CONVERT_NON_NATIVE_ONLY);
            return builder.build();
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I neither use an embedded instance for testing nor the `@DataNeo4jTest`. Wanted to review the created data inside my locally running instance.

I also recommend not using the embedded database in test but test containers aka "the real thing" you would run in production: https://medium.com/neo4j/testing-your-neo4j-based-java-application-34bef487cc3c

For final reference, here is the `POM` i used. Please accept the answer if the thing is useful and solves your issue.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>so_re</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so_re</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Amazing answer! It seems I was close to finding the solution, but Spring documentation is not correct? I was trying to write my query as: `@Query("MATCH (p:Person)-[r:RATED]->(s:Skill) WHERE id(p)={person} RETURN p,r,s")`. In the reference documentation examples, they use the [syntax](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/5.1.10.RELEASE/reference/html/#_query_results) I tried but it seems it doesn't work correctly. The prime example would be `getUsersWhoRatedMovieFromTitle` method of the linked chapter.

Comment: Thank you! You can use `{n}` with n being a positional parameter or the SPel Expression notion. With the positional parameter, you would not be able do dereference the id and you would need to expose your method as `findByXXX(Long personId)` and I would find that ugly from an API perspective.

Comment: "The named or indexed parameter {param} will be substituted by the actual method parameter. Node and relationship entities are handled directly and converted into their respective ids." The example I mentioned uses the entity class (Movie), not the id itself? Why does the id dereference work in that example using `WHERE id(movie)={movieId}` but I cannot use `WHERE id(p)={person}`? Sorry for being repetitive :/

Comment: I'll have to check that, I'll come back to you, but won't manage today.

Comment: I apologize, I mispoke. I forgot to return the start and end node. The mapping works fine. Sorry again!